# PHP: Sort multidimensional array, but keep its substructure

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional arrays with the following structure:

```
$arr[0][0] = 1.24;
$arr[0][1] = 5.21;
$arr[0][2] = 2.72;
$arr[0][3] = 1.89;
$arr[0][4] = 4.62;

$arr[1][0] = 3.45;
$arr[1][1] = 5.61;
$arr[1][2] = 2.62;
$arr[1][3] = 1.12;
$arr[1][4] = 1.35;
```

This array should get sorted while keeping the suborder of $arr[0] and $arr[1], so the result looks like this:

```
$arr[0][0] = 1.24;
$arr[1][0] = 3.45;
$arr[0][1] = 5.21;
$arr[0][2] = 2.72;
$arr[0][3] = 1.89;
$arr[0][4] = 4.62;
$arr[1][2] = 2.62;
$arr[1][3] = 1.12;
$arr[1][4] = 1.35;
$arr[1][1] = 5.61;
```

I do not care in which form the result get saved, but I need both keys and the value. Hope you understand and can help me.

Comment: Show your effort. We are not here to write code for you.

Comment: can you explain the expected result, the array doesn't seem to have any kind of sorting!!

Comment: I could do it myself with a lot of loops, but my acctual problem is quite larger. This is just a minimal working example and I was hoping for a short and efficient way.

Comment: Well at first it compares $arr[0][0] with $arr[1][0]. $arr[0][0] is smaller so this goes first. Next it compares $arr[0][1] with $arr[1][0], $arr[1][0] is smaller. And so on...

Comment: where $arr[1][1] = 5.61 in output?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot it. It is the very last one.

Answer (score 0):

How about looping the outer array and sorting the inner?

```
foreach ($arr as $id => $data) {
 sort($data);
 $arr[$id] = $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                $arr[0][0] = 1.24;
                $arr[0][1] = 5.21;
                $arr[0][2] = 2.72;
                $arr[0][3] = 1.89;
                $arr[0][4] = 4.62;
                $arr[1][0] = 3.45;
                $arr[1][1] = 5.61;
                $arr[1][2] = 2.62;
                $arr[1][3] = 1.12;
                $arr[1][4] = 1.35;
                $size = count($arr);
                $outArr= array();
                foreach($arr[0] as $key =>$value)
                {
                    $resArr = array();
                    for($i = 0 ; $i< $size ; $i++)
                    {
                        $resArr[] = $arr[$i][$key] ;
                    }
                    sort($resArr);
                    $outArr[$key] = $resArr;
                }
                echo "<pre>";

                print_r($outArr);
```

Check if this is a closer solution.